# Setting the value of objects in XAML from the .xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I can declare a checkbox in XAML like so

```
<CheckBox Content="Accepted" Height="71" Name="checkBox" />
```

When this screen loads I want to check the data associated with the screen and set it if the box is checked, or it its not checked.

```
public TripDetails()
{
   string yesString = "YES";
    if (String.ReferenceEquals(meeting.accepted, yesString))
    {
        // set the checkbox
    }
    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

What I cannot understand is how to set the checkbox declared in the XAML from within my cooresponding xaml.cs file.

Could somebody please advise what should go where my 
    // set the checkbox
is.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something...since you've named the CheckBox "`checkBox`", it should just be

```
this.checkBox.IsChecked = !this.checkBox.IsChecked;
```